# What is the difference between node.js request and restify client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, restify, http-request

Both seem to serve similar purpose. I am using restify server as REST API server. Does it mean it is better that I use restify client as well?

http://restify.com/#client-api

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request` is a small module that makes it easier for you to handle HTTP requests in Node.js.

`restify` is a framework that lets you create REST API server very easily. It handles all the nitpicky things you would have to do like routing, etc.

Inevitably, you could probably make your own RESTful API in Node.js by simply using the `request` module. `restify` [made their own custom one](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/5.x/lib/request.js) that they use within the framework.

Comment: Can restify client replace request module? http://restify.com/#client-api 
Does request module have better community support, say on stackoverflow?

Comment: @user16891328 I don't think replace is the appropriate term. Rather restify comes bundled with its own version of the request module. They have documentation [here](http://restify.com/#request-api). In terms of community support, they both are very popular. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are handling a simple HTTP request, doesn't make sense to bring in all of restify. If you are trying to make a REST API, you probably don't want to build it from scratch with just the request module.